# flutter agora rtc engine : error: Method not found: '$enumDecode'

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using agora_rtc_engine package with version 4.2.2 and I get this error when I run my app:

Error: Method not found: '$enumDecode'.
$enumDecode(_$AudioDeviceTestVolumeTypeEnumMap, json['volumeType'])

I have also tried to use the latest version but I get the same error.
I'd like to know how solve this issue.

Comment: try flutter clean, then add the latest version and pub get. Hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: I have done this but it's still not working

Comment: Have you added all the required permissions in the manifest.

Comment: All of them are added according to the package documentation

Comment: can you provide code snippet where you are initialising it.